# Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, django-tests

I have a pet project in which I use django-rest framework and docker-compose. Everything seems to be working fine except tests.py.Test runner just doesn't see them. docker-compose acts like I don't have any. Here are my files:

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'python3 taskmanager/manage.py makemigrations && taskmanager/manage.py migrate && taskmanager/manage.py test && taskmanager/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

tests.py:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from .models import Task


class TaskTests(APITestCase):

def setUp(self):
    Task.objects.create(name='Run marathon', description='Need to run a marathon')
    Task.objects.create(name='Lie on the beach', description='Need some more sunlight')

def test_create_task(self):
    url = reverse('tasks_list_url')
    data = {'name': 'Buy milk', 'description': 'Need some milk'}
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    self.assertEqual(Task.objects.get(id=3).name, 'Buy milk')

def test_get_single_task(self):
    url = reverse('task_detail_url', args=[2])
    response = self.client.get(url, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

def test_get_tasks_list(self):
    url = reverse('tasks_list_url')
    response = self.client.get(url, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

location of tests.py:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtEto.png)

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand what you are trying to do, nor is there enough to understand what the problem is.

Comment: what does your project structure look like ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, because there isn't enough information. Are you running pytest? What is your command to run the test? What is the traceback. Please update your question for everyone else to understand this better.

Sometimes, the test runner assumes that the test file is of the form `test_***.py`. Maybe that's what's happening? Do try to change the test file to something like `test_example.py` and run the command again.